# Django 3 admin link is coming without css

Tags: python, django

The Admin link is missing css, returns 404 when doing view source.
The .conf file is

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/django/medicalai
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /static /var/www/django/medicalai
<Directory /var/www/django/medicalai/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/django/medicalai>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess medicalai python-path=/var/www/django/medicalai python-home=/var/www/django/venv
WSGIProcessGroup medicalai
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django/medicalai/medicalai/wsgi.py
WSGIPassAuthorization On

</VirtualHost>
```

The Static file contains.

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
```

The static folder and files are here.
/var/www/django/medicalai/static/admin/css

All the files and folders are downloaded by using 
python manage.py collectstatic.

**But there is no CSS when I open http://example.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/**
Please help to point the mistake.

Comment: Can you please point the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue could happen because you do not have  **STATIC_ROOT** configured when you run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

What this setting does is to copy all the static files from all the **STATICFILES_DIRS** directories into a single ROOT prepared for production serving.

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/django/medicalai/static/'
```

Comment: I remove all the content from static folder then add STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/django/medicalai/static/' and run the collectstatic as u said. Dut it still not fetching <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/admin/css/login.css"> giving 404.

Comment: Is it something apache .cong file stopping the access?

Comment: How do you load the static css file into django ?  The syntax for loading css files into django templates should have the static modifier and be dynamically loaded `
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/static/admin/css/base.css' %}"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/static/admin/css/login.css' %}">`  Also, when you run collectstatic does the root folder gets populated ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the root folder gets populated. Till now there is no app, m just install Django and try to open the admin.

Comment: I did saw  the '/static' is missing from Alias static in apache.conf. This should be `Alias /static /var/www/django/medicalai/static`

Comment: These works thank u very much, do I need to add the /media as well.

Comment: You're welcome. You only need media if you intend to store files (videos, photos) on your server